# Corda - Can a CorDapp build using Corda V1.0 be deployed in production environment?

Tags: corda

I have build a CorDapp using "Yo!CorDapp" example (https://github.com/corda/spring-observable-stream), over release-v1 of Corda platform.

The CorDapp has four nodes - Controller node (provides network map service and validating notary service), "node A", "node B" and "node C". Following are the flows defined in the app -

Flow 1: "Node A" sends a trade request to "Node B". "Node C" is also notified.

Flow 2: "Node B" approves the trade request, self-signs it, gets signature from A and closes the trade. "Node C" is also notified.

Since the CorDapp is running well, I want to deploy it in the production site.

1. Is it recommendable to deploy such a CorDapp in production?
2. What would be the standard practice for deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be run in production. But, if it is just a small app that has not already been deployed I would just increase the corda version to v3/4 and fix any errors.

There are so many improvements in these versions that it is not worth using such a low version for an application not already in use.